# Binding node webkit nwdirectory to ngmodel

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, node-webkit

Node-Webkit exposes a way to select a directory with `<input type='file' nwdirectory/>` but how can you bind a angular model to the selected folder?

I tried:

```
.directive("getDir", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            getDir: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.getDir = changeEvent.target.files[0]
                })
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

and on the HTML of the controller (routed partial):

```
{{ location }}

<div class="uk-form-file">
    <button class="uk-button">New Location</button>
    <input type="file" getDir="location" nwdirectory>
</div>
```

The actual controller:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

But after selecting still nothing shows on `{{ location }}`

Answer (score 1):

1. In html you need to use dash-delimited style like instead of `getDir="location"` write `get-dir="location"`. See [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for reference.
2. You want to print `{{ location }}`, but in your directive you are assigning value of file target to `scope.getDir` , so you can print it using the same variable name like {{ getDir }}

Please check fixed code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aleksanyan/t34L60n1/29/).

http://jsfiddle.net/aleksanyan/t34L60n1/29/